# bitmap.recycle() not working

Tags: java, android, memory, bitmap

I have trouble with draw background activitie on canvas (background on all size of display) App crashed because OutOfMemoryError.

I try use recycle() and I put this code if I arrived launch activity for recycle bitmap in it.

```
private void RecyklGO(Bitmap bitmap,Bitmap bitmap2) {
        bitmap.recycle();
        bitmap2.recycle();
    }
```

But I was watching on Memory in androidstudio I didn't see change.

Next I stepping program and i see so, .recykle no run.

I want delete bitmap which told Game Over, and if user tap on Play Again I want delete this bitmaps, because I want put background. (activity is on Canvas, so all is written on it. No switch activity, only rewrite canvas.)

Thanks for any idea.

_____________ more code ___________________________-

```
bcgGO = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.bcg_go);
    bcgGO = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(
            bcgGO, (int) (srk ), (int) (vsk), false);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bcgGO, srk / 5, vsk / 4.2F, paint);
```

variables srk and vsk are size of displays on Bitmap.createScaledBitmap line crashed app. 
On this activity haven't bitmaps.

Comment: Too less input, Kindly share your maximum code, to figure out how and where memory increasing.

Comment: I did put code where app crashed., or will put all code from app?

Comment: Better to share at least the class or all code responsible to increase the memory, so that any one can able to find the exact problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your input I identified one problem, As your code is :

```
bcgGO = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.bcg_go);
bcgGO = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(
        bcgGO, (int) (srk ), (int) (vsk), false);
canvas.drawBitmap(bcgGO, srk / 5, vsk / 4.2F, paint);
```

In first line you are creating a Bitmap called bcgGO. But in second line you are again overwriting it by scalled bitmap. I think it is creating problem for you, because you are just overwriting the reference. So the result is you main bitmap is still in memory without any ref. object and you can't recycle it because you have no reference of that.
Check a little modification, It might increase the memory performance :

```
    Bitmapt actBcgGO = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.bcg_go);
    bcgGO = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(
            actBcgGO, (int) (srk ), (int) (vsk), false);
    actBcgGO.recycle();
    canvas.drawBitmap(bcgGO, srk / 5, vsk / 4.2F, paint);
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: Ok, now actBcgGO recycled, but I need recycled bcgGO, too, no?

Comment: No, as per your code, you are not going to use your actual bitmap image anyway. Because you are already overwriting the reference of the actual bitmap by scaled bitmap. So after creating scaled bitmap the actual bitmap(actBcgGo) should be recycled. Yes after use you can recycle it too, if not re-using anywhere.

Comment: So, now is ewerything okay? If i write bitmap to canvas I rewrite my code with soce from you? 

because if I wathching process of memory usages in android studio, before your code (your code open bitmap on background in display size) and after method with your code isn't the same. I thing If everything is okay, must be the same, no? 

(I will deleted all bitmaps and compare changes)

Comment: If deleted all bitmaps Use memory is constant for every method.

Comment: The problem as per your code shared, was that Every original bitmap was in memory and never recycled. Now in updated code you are recycling actual bigger bitmap just after getting your scaled bitmap. So it will change a lot, I wish :)

Comment: If I rapid switch game over and play app crashed.. :( and have on memory log in androidstudio,  alocated and a lot free value.

Comment: Add this tag in your application tag  in manifest - android:largeHeap="true"

Comment: what doing this tag? android:largeHeap="true"

Comment: this tag increases the HeapSize for your app, so your app will get more memory, so the chances of OutOfMemory will be much less.